# solaris ssh port forward

Tags: mysql, ssh, solaris, ssh-tunnel

I have been trying to create a ssh tunnel from a Linux box to a mysql server on a Solaris box with: `ssh -i <some_private_key_file> -L 3333:localhost:3306 root@<Solaris box>` command on the Linux box.

On trying to connect to the mysql server from the Linux box with command `mysql -P 3333 -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p`, I am getting the following error: `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0`

Now running the sshd (Solaris) on debug level 3 I get the following error:

```
debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype direct-tcpip rchan 3 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: server_request_direct_tcpip: originator 127.0.0.1 port 34100, target localhost port 3306
Received request to connect to host localhost port 3306, but the request was denied.
debug1: server_input_channel_open: failure direct-tcpip
```

And also getting the following error: `channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed`

On the Solaris machine:

- SSH version : Sun_SSH_1.1
- cat /etc/release : Solaris 10 11/06 s10x_u3wos_10 X86
- uanme -a : SunOS unknown 5.10 Generic_118855-33 i86pc i386 i86pc

On the Linix box :

- SSH version : OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed : There was two conflicting `AllowTcpForwarding` value in the sshd_config. Somehow the first one with value `no` was taking precedence. Might be a bug with OpenSSH 4.2p1